# The column name id was not found in this ResultSet

Tags: spring-boot, psql

```
@Query(value = "SELECT s FROM logines.work_hour s WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(s.start_time,  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi')\\:\\:timestamp BETWEEN :start_time\\:\\:timestamp AND now()\\:\\:timestamp", nativeQuery = true)
List<WorkHour> findByStartTime(@Param("start_time") String startTime);
```

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name id was not found in this ResultSet.

What might be an issue?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. It seems that in some scenarios the result columns can not be mapped to the output entity if we use table alias in SELECT statement.

```
SELECT t FROM my_table t WHERE ....;
```

The same query was working in one cases and failing in others. I found out that the problem goes away if we use a star `*` instead of the alias:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be due to the usage of only s in @Query.  replacing s with all db column names with it i.e., s.coloumn1, s.column2, s.column3 will fix the issue.

Comment: This works indeed but isn't there a more conventient way?